# how to tell Photos library that source files are in different Volume

Tags: macos, backup, photos, photos.app, disk-volume

I want to figure out a way to tell Photos that all original source files are in exactly the same place as before but on a different volume. (The equivalent of changing all their paths' reference to `/Volumes/driveA/...` to `/Volumes/driveB/...`.)

My old external hard drive failed, I was able to recover the files from somewhere else, and I had to restore the files to a differently-named external hard drive.

Now that I'm trying to share, or create picture with, pictures from my library, a dialog comes up saying:

> The volume for “IMG_[XXXX].JPG” cannot be found. Connect the disk or mount the server volume needed, then try again.

I select "Apply to All," every time that dialog comes up, I point it to the proper source file and it finds it... but then it asks me for a reference to a picture in another folder.

All the photos are in exactly the same place relative to each other, it's just a different volume. I thought Photos would be smart enough to at least try to create relative paths (a relatively simple thing to do) and attempt to find other missing source files through those guessed relative paths, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Note that I did *not* copy the items to the Photos library, whose location hasn't changed. That means that I need to point Photos towards the new location of the original pictures, not to the library files directory.

Is there a manual way to just change the volume of the source files for all the pictures in my library?

Comment: Based on my experience, even I intended to keep the path always the same (for me it's /Volumes/data/picture/photo), I have the same problem. I assume Apple just wants everyone stores all their photos in their startup drive.

This problem was there since iPhoto era... Comparing with Google Photos, Apple Photo is nearly unusable. Sad.

Comment: PS: I was trying to answer this question, saying there is no way to fix it for now, and was deleted by someone cannot simply read my answer. Let me as you a question who deleted my answer: have you tried to put your Photos library in different hard-drives, and tried to mount them in the same path? Do you have better knowledge than me? Share it if you do, otherwise try to LEARN from my answer instead of deleting it!

Comment: I wish I had enough reputation on this site to see the deleted answer and/or to try to undelete it to build on it. I don't know if I even got a notification about a new answer. either way, thank you! if you try again maybe it won't be deleted?